# How tidy is thread id assignment?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I did the following experiment:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void t()
{
    std :: cout << std :: this_thread :: get_id() << std :: endl;
}

void f()
{
    std :: cout << std :: this_thread :: get_id() << std :: endl;
}

int main()
{
    std :: cout << std :: this_thread :: get_id() << std :: endl;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        std :: thread d(t);
        d.join();

        std :: thread g(f);
        g.join();
    }
}
```

and noticed that the resulting list of `thread_id`s would always be the same. In other words, in this case the `thread_id` was continuously re-assigned whenever the thread was joined and re-opened.

Now, can I have any form of certainty that this will always happen? Or can it happen that a `thread_id` is assigned only once, then always different `thread_id`s get assigned in a random-like fashion?

Comment: What happens if you do the joins after you create both threads?  When you join you  end the thread.

Comment: I'd think that the only guarantee would be that if two threads are active that the ids will be different. ID assigning is probably implementation dependent.

Comment: @NathanOliver if I join after both threads are created I get two alternating values. Quite pretty. However, as flatmouse pointed out, this will not work on all platforms.

Comment: @MatteoMonti It is going to be implementation defined.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @NathanOliver I need a pool of resources, so that whenever a thread is started if one of the resources is available then it gets assigned, otherwise a new resource is created and added to the pool. This is something that is trivial to do with `thread_local` where you can have non-trivial destructors to release the resource, but I am working under Mac OS Xcode. There you only get `__thread`, which doesn't allow non-trivial destructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot assume that it will always be the same. On VS2015 I get the following:

```
...
2444
18472
29912
25180
6612
29440
13220
4684
14004
12388
16424
26320
25948
28076
30904
6396
1160
4228
...
```

Comment: Sigh. Gotta find another way then! Thank you!

Comment: Sad to see there is no shortcut here, happy that we could rule it out quickly. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's some documentation here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/id

emphasis is mine

> The class thread::id is a lightweight, trivially copyable class that serves as a unique identifier of std::thread objects.
>
> Instances of this class may also hold the special distinct value that does not represent any thread. Once a thread has finished, the value of std::thread::id **may** be reused by another thread.
>
> This class is designed for use as key in associative containers, both ordered and unordered.